# Can I apply to a PhD program if I will be graduating with my undergraduate degree in the summer term instead of the spring term?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am interested in applying for PhD programs for fall admittance. While I think most undergraduates will graduate in the spring, take the summer off or do something otherwise productive, and start their program in the fall, I want to use the summer semester to finish up some general education requirements.

So my basic timeline would be:

- Apply for grad schools in the late fall/early January, and of course be doing coursework in the fall semester
- Take more classes in the spring, and hopefully be accepted somewhere
- Finish up final degree degree requirements in the summer (only general education requirements), and graduate
- Enter grad school in the fall

I want to do this so I can take more math classes in the fall and spring, and finish up my required art class and economics class in the summer. I have never heard about undergraduates doing this. Is it common, and is it okay to do? I cannot find much about it online. Is there any reason NOT to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming USA) Yes, you can apply if you are graduating in the summer.  No, I do not see any reason why you should not do this.  You should probably explain your plan and the reasons for it in your application.